# Why use while loop in levelDB's cache (function Resize)?

Tags: c++, caching, while-loop, leveldb

When I see the implement of levelDB's cache, [address](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/util/cache.cc). I can not understand why it use while loop in for loop(in function Resize), and I think it can replace by if statement. I hope someone can help me.

```
 void Resize() {
    uint32_t new_length = 4;
    while (new_length < elems_) {
      new_length *= 2;
    }
    LRUHandle** new_list = new LRUHandle*[new_length];
    memset(new_list, 0, sizeof(new_list[0]) * new_length);
    uint32_t count = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length_; i++) {
      LRUHandle* h = list_[i];
      while (h != NULL) {
        LRUHandle* next = h->next_hash;
        uint32_t hash = h->hash;
        LRUHandle** ptr = &new_list[hash & (new_length - 1)];
        h->next_hash = *ptr;
        *ptr = h;
        h = next;
        count++;
      }
    }
    assert(elems_ == count);
    delete[] list_;
    list_ = new_list;
    length_ = new_length;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: @ToothlessRebel I don not understand why the author use while, and if statement may works.

Answer (score 1):

`list_` is apparently an array of linked lists. `while (h != NULL)`, combined with `h = next` (where `next` is `h->next_hash`), means the while loop will operate on all the elements of every linked list, stopping only when the last element is reached (when `h` becomes `NULL`, either because the list was empty or because `next_hash` of an element was `NULL`).

If you replaced it with `if (h != NULL)`, it would only work on the first element of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like list_ is a dynamic array of singly linked lists.

I assume the list_ looks something like the following

```
list_[0]-> node_1 -> node_2 -> null
list_[1]-> node_3 -> null
list_[2]-> null
....
list_[n]-> node_m-1 -> node_m -> null
```

To properly copy all of the elements into new_list you need to use the while loop. Otherwise any element that is not directly addressable from list_ will not be copied/hashed into the new_list.  In the above diagram that would mean node_2 and node_m+1 would not be added to the new_list.

The new_list will keep the same shape but should have fewer collisions.

Using an if statement the new_list would look something like:

```
new_list[0]-> node_1 -> null
new_list[1]-> null
new_list[2]-> node_2 -> null
...
new_list[p-1]-> node_k -> null
new_list[p] -> null
```

That is each item in new_list would point to a list of 1 or zero elements.
Note node_1 in this diagram isn't necessarily the same as node 1 in the above diagram.

Using an If statement instead of a while loop will also lead to a memory leak since you can no longer access all of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `list_[i]` has a sub list, `while` inside the `for` loop is looping over the sub list.

Answer (score 0):

The if-statement doesn't work, if you have two elements `list_[i]` and `list_[j]` are both hashed to a same index `new_list[m]`. In such a case, you have to use while-statement to merge two buckets. Meanwhile, the length of every bucket in this implementation is less than 1 on average, so the while-statement here is actually as fast as the if-statement.

Comment: it seems the collision not going to happen, if the length of list is always power of 2. So maybe the while statement is a generic approach. Anyway, the while is not "expensive" here.